# convert string data in dataframe into double

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file containing double type.When i load to a dataframe i got this message telling me that the type string is java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double although my data are numeric.How do i get a dataframe from this csv file containing double type.how should i modify my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{ArrayType, DoubleType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split
import scala.collection.mutable._

object Example extends App {

val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("my-spark-app").getOrCreate()
val data=spark.read.csv("C://lpsa.data").toDF("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9")
val data2=data.select("col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7")
```

What sould i make to transform each row in the dataframe into double type? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use `select` with `cast`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

data.select(Seq("col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7").map(
  c => col(c).cast("double")
): _*)
```

or pass schema to the reader:

- define the schema:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

  val cols = Seq(
    "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9"
  )

  val doubleCols = Set("col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7")

  val schema =  StructType(cols.map(
    c => StructField(c, if (doubleCols contains c) DoubleType else StringType)
  ))
  ```
- and use it as an argument for `schema` method

  ```
  spark.read.schema(schema).csv(path)
  ```

It is also possible to use schema inference:

```
spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").csv(path)
```

but it is much more expensive.

Comment: What needs to be imported?

Comment: @Sade All imports for schema are present. And `col` is `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col`

Comment: Thanks it works now but when I run df.show() it states NameError: name 'df' is not defined. Why is this so? Another q, does Seq (...) only select the specified columns and drop the rest or does it select the specified columns , update it and still the rest of the columns? It seems like it is dropping it.

Comment: @Sade Double check your code. Sounds like it is not the name you've used.

Comment: I ended up using  this: %scala
val df2 = df.withColumn("start_t", df("start_t").cast("string"))

Answer (score 1):

I believe using sparks `inferSchema` option comes in handy while reading the csv file. Below is the code to automatically detect your columns as double type :

```
val data = spark.read
                .format("csv")
                .option("header", "false")
                .option("inferSchema", "true")
                .load("C://lpsa.data").toDF()


Note: I am using spark version 2.2.0
```